# Is it possible to find two disjoint open sets in topology $\mathbb{R}_{\text{har}}$?

Tags: general-topology

I'm working through the book *Topology Through Inquiry* by Francis Su and Michael Starbird. There is an exercise (3.9) about a topological space they call $\mathbb{R}_{\text{har}}$. It is defined on the set $\mathbb{R}$ with basis all sets of the form $(a, b)$ or $(a,b)-H$ (i.e. $(a,b)\backslash H$), where $H = \{1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. There are two subquestions to which I found the answer:

1. In the topological space $\mathbb{R}_{\text{har}}$, what is the closure of the set $H = \{1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?
   *I found the close of $H$ to be $H$ itself.*
2. In the topological space $\mathbb{R}_{\text{har}}$, what is the closure of the set $H^- = \{-1/n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?
   *Here I found the closure to be $H^- \cup \{0\}$*.
3. Is it possible to find disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ in $\mathbb{R}_{\text{har}}$, such that $0\in U$ and $H\subset V$?
   *This is where I'm stuck. I believe it's not possible, but I can't think of a definitive reason why it's not. Is my suspicion correct? How does one show that this is not possible?*

Comment: Do you mean$(a, b) \setminus H$, or do you mean $(a, b)$ translated by each element of $H$?

Comment: Ah yes, that notation seems a little specific to the book. But I mean $(a,b)\backslash H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct. 2. Correct.

Let $0\in C$ where $C$ is a basic open set. Then there exist $a, b$ with $a<0<b$ and $$C\supset (a,b)\setminus H\supset (0,b)\setminus H\supset (0,1/n)\setminus H$$ for some $n\in \Bbb N.$

Let $D$ be a basic open set with $1/(n+1)\in D.$ Then $D\ne (a',b')\setminus H$, else $1/(n+1)\not\in D$. So there exist $a', b'$ with $a'<1/(n+1)<b'$ and $D=(a',b').$

Let $e=\max (a', 1/(n+2)\,).$ Then $C\cap D\supset (e,1/(n+1)\,)\ne\emptyset.$

Remarks. The base (basis) for the standard (usual) topology on $\Bbb R$ is a subset of the base for $\Bbb R_{har}$ so any standard open (or closed) set is open (or closed) in $\Bbb R_{har}.$ So $\{0\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R_{har} .$ So  $\Bbb R_{har}$  is not a normal ($T_4$) space.

Comment: There is a more common name for $\Bbb R_{har}$ but I don't remember it.

Comment: Munkres calls it $\Bbb R_K$ for some reason and that’s the only other text I know that uses this space as a simple Hausdorff non-regular space. It’s also connected but not path-connected e.g. It’s not in Steen and Seebach IIRC.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! I had to double-check what "normal space" meant, because the term is explained later on in the book.